# Outlook Addin on-send feature not working as expected on desktop

Tags: office365, office-js, outlook-web-addins

I'm writing an Office add-in for Outlook. This add-in consists of a task pane that can be used during creating an appointment (`AppointmentOrganizerCommandSurface`). This task pane contains a form with some inputs. When the user sends the appointment, the on-send feature also sends (or it's supposed to send) a request to my API.

This flow works fine one Outlook web, with attendees on the appointment and the information in the add-in side the API is called. But it's not working on the desktop side.

I've tried with different versions the last one I've tried is `Monthly Enterprise version 2005 (12827.20538)` and it just shows the add-in is working on my request but it does nothing else.

I've configured as it says [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/outlook-on-send-addins?tabs=windows#install-outlook-add-ins-that-use-on-send). Do I need any further configuration? Am I missing something?

EDIT: The windows is `version 10.0.14393` and the `build 14393`.

Just in case this is the part in the manifest for desktop:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<OfficeApp xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/appforoffice/1.1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:bt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/officeappbasictypes/1.0" xsi:type="MailApp">
  <Id>91b11704-b973-41cf-bd3a-217ad5bafce9</Id>
    <Version>1.0.0.0</Version>
    <ProviderName>Add-In</ProviderName>
    <DefaultLocale>en-US</DefaultLocale>
    <DisplayName DefaultValue="Add-In" />
    <Description DefaultValue="Add-In Sample" />
    <IconUrl DefaultValue="https://localhost:4000/assets/logo-32.png"/>
    <HighResolutionIconUrl DefaultValue="https://localhost:4000/assets/icon_2.png"/>
    <SupportUrl DefaultValue="https://localhost/p" />
    <AppDomains>
      <AppDomain>https://localhost:4000</AppDomain>
    </AppDomains>
  <Hosts>
    <Host Name="Mailbox"/>
  </Hosts>
  <Requirements>
    <Sets>
      <Set Name="Mailbox" MinVersion="1.1"/>
    </Sets>
  </Requirements>
  <FormSettings>
    <Form xsi:type="ItemEdit">
        <DesktopSettings>
          <SourceLocation DefaultValue="https://localhost:4000/taskpane.html" />
        </DesktopSettings>
    </Form>
  </FormSettings>
  <Permissions>ReadWriteItem</Permissions>
  <Rule xsi:type="RuleCollection" Mode="Or">
    <Rule xsi:type="ItemIs" ItemType="Appointment" FormType="Edit"/>
  </Rule>
  <DisableEntityHighlighting>false</DisableEntityHighlighting>
  <VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_0">
    <!-- On Send requires VersionOverridesV1_1 -->
    <VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides/1.1" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_1">
      <Description resid="residAppDescription" />
      <Requirements>
        <bt:Sets DefaultMinVersion="1.3">
          <bt:Set Name="Mailbox" />
        </bt:Sets>
      </Requirements>
      <Hosts>
        <Host xsi:type="MailHost">
          <DesktopFormFactor>
            <!-- The functionfile and function name to call on message send.  -->
            <!-- In this particular case the function validateBody will be called within the JavaScript code referenced in residUILessFunctionFileUrl. -->
            <FunctionFile resid="residUILessFunctionFileUrl" />
            <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="AppointmentOrganizerCommandSurface">
            <OfficeTab id="TabDefault">
              <Group id="msgReadGroup">
                <Label resid="GroupLabel"/>
                <Control xsi:type="Button" id="apptReadOpenPaneButton">
                  <Label resid="TaskpaneButton.Label"/>
                  <Supertip>
                    <Title resid="TaskpaneButton.Label"/>
                    <Description resid="TaskpaneButton.Tooltip"/>
                  </Supertip>
                  <Icon>
                    <bt:Image size="16" resid="Icon.16x16"/>
                    <bt:Image size="32" resid="Icon.32x32"/>
                    <bt:Image size="80" resid="Icon.80x80"/>
                  </Icon>
                  <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                    <SourceLocation resid="Taskpane.Url"/>
                  </Action>
                </Control>
              </Group>
            </OfficeTab>
          </ExtensionPoint>
          </DesktopFormFactor>
        </Host>
      </Hosts>
      <Resources>
        <bt:Images>
        <bt:Image id="Icon.16x16" DefaultValue="https://localhost:4000/assets/logo-32.png"/>
        <bt:Image id="Icon.32x32" DefaultValue="https://localhost:4000/assets/logo-32.png"/>
        <bt:Image id="Icon.80x80" DefaultValue="https://localhost:4000/assets/logo-32.png"/>
      </bt:Images>
      <bt:Urls>
        <bt:Url id="residUILessFunctionFileUrl" DefaultValue="https://localhost:4000/taskpane.html"/>
        <bt:Url id="Taskpane.Url" DefaultValue="https://localhost:4000/taskpane.html"/>
      </bt:Urls>
      <bt:ShortStrings>
        <bt:String id="GroupLabel" DefaultValue="Add-in"/>
        <bt:String id="TaskpaneButton.Label" DefaultValue="Open Add-in"/>
      </bt:ShortStrings>
      <bt:LongStrings>
        <bt:String id="TaskpaneButton.Tooltip" DefaultValue="Opens add-in."/>
        <bt:String id="ActionButton.Tooltip" DefaultValue="Open add-in."/>
      </bt:LongStrings>
      </Resources>
    </VersionOverrides>
  </VersionOverrides>
</OfficeApp>
```

The snippet for the action we call is as follows:

```js
const action = async event => {
  const savedHeader = (await Office.context.roamingSettings.get("persistData")) || "Nothing found.";
  const savedId = await Office.context.roamingSettings.get("id");
  const savedInputFields = await Office.context.roamingSettings.get("formData");
  const savedEventUpdate = await Office.context.roamingSettings.get("isUpdate");

  const config = {
    headers: savedHeader.headers
  };

  getCalendarData().then(calendarData => {
    const body = {
      appointment: {
        title: calendarData.subject,
        place: calendarData.location,
        begin_at: calendarData.start,
        end_at: calendarData.end
      },
      visitors: savedInputFields,
      outlook: {
        event_id: savedId
      }
    };

    send(config, body, savedId, savedEventUpdate, event);
  });
};

const send = async (config, body, savedId, savedEventUpdate, event) => {
  if (savedEventUpdate) {
    await updateEvent(savedId, body, config);
  else {
      createAppointment(body, config)
  }
  event.completed();
};
```

`getCalendarData` is just a wrapper to `Office.context.mailbox.item` retrieving data from the form.

I've also tried with something simpler like this (similar to the documentation samples):

```js
function action (event) {
  mailboxItem.body.getAsync("html", { asyncContext: event }, function(asyncResult){
    mailboxItem.notificationMessages.addAsync('NoSend', { type: 'errorMessage', message: 'Blocked' });
    asyncResult.asyncContext.completed({ allowEvent: false });
  });
}
```

Comment: Could you provide Windows version and build number? And could you tell us more about the repro? On desktop Outlook, is the on-send entry point loaded at all? Or do you know if it's an issue with some API calls?

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT The entry point is probably loaded because when I press on send it says my add-in is working on the request. There's any way to check what is happening inside the on send code when using a desktop client? I couldn't check it attaching the JIT debugger nor using the F12 DevTools. The API seems to work properly, I've added a button that makes the call by itself and works just fine. Also making the request from the outside works too. I've tried to make a simple test, just a function that blocks the sent action, but it works just creating an email and not when is a meeting

Comment: I am experiencing the same problem in the Outlook desktop. It works well in web browsers, but not on the desktop application.

Comment: Just to confirm, the onsend addin works as expected on messages but doesn't on Appointments? Could you also share the code snippet of the function call that happens during onSend? Would it also be possible for you to share your manifest so we can test it on our end to make an informed decision on what might be going on?

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT The simpler version that I tried works in mails, but not during appointments. The API call one does not seem to work in either. I edited the question and added the snippet and a full version of the manifest.

Comment: The version of Windows 10 you are on is older. https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/office/blogs/microsoft-edge-webview-for-office-add-ins/ So it is using IE instead of Edge to run your add-ins. In your function file, it looks like you have an arrow function, which is not supported by IE. I suspect if you ran this add-in in OWA on IE you would hit the same error. Something you can do is in IE, go to Advanced Settings and have it pop up a dialog every time a script error occurs. (this should also give you a chance to attach to iexplore.exe)

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT using IE11 on OWA works just fine. We are bundling javascript with babel and Webpack so it's not a real problem. Is there any way to attach iexplorer F12 (or Edge) tools to outlook when running on-send? I can do it for task pane, but not for on-send.

Comment: You can attach Visual Studio in script mode to iexplore.exe to debug what is going on. Make sure you boot up Internet Explorer and hit Tools->Options->Advanced. And uncheck "disable script debugging" And enable "Display Notification About Every script Error"